# Gettint text from lastline in richtextbox

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I want to copy the last line of a rich textbox.
I am avoiding  `Dim lastLine As String = RichTextBox1.Lines(RichTextBox1.Lines.Length - 1)`as
it's not working properly, as It works just if there are atleast 2 lines in it.
I'm trying with `MsgBox(RichTextBox1.Lines(UBound(richtextbox1.Lines)))` but the problem is that even if the richtextbox has just 1 line of text but the cursor is in the second empty line, it will give back "" as I think the software is reading the empty 2nd line.
There is a solution to that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get the last non-empty line:

```vb
RichTextBox1.Lines.Where(Function(line) line <> String.Empty).Last()
```

There are some potential issues with that. If there's no text at all or if there are multiple lines but they are all empty, that will throw an exception. To allow for that, you can call `LastOrDefault` instead, in which case it would return `Nothing`.

If you only want to exclude the last empty line, e.g. if you have some text followed by a line break and then another line break then you want to get the first of those two empty lines, then you can't really do it in one line:

```vb
Dim lines = RichTextBox1.Lines
Dim upperBound = lines.GetUpperBound(0)
Dim lastLine = lines(upperBound)

If lastLine = String.Empty Then
    If upperBound > 0 Then
        lastLine = lines(upperBound - 1)
    Else
        lastLine = Nothing
    End If
End If

'Use lastLine here.
```